# How to customize drop-down menu

Tags: react-select

I'm interested in determining if its possible for me to completely customize the drop-down that appears in response to a user typing text into a select2 text field (using the react-select component).

I want the text to generate output similar to what appears in Apple's Spotlight OS feature (see screenshot - in which I typed the text 'mini').

Is this possible using react-select and if so - how ? Are there samples ?

I found this repo ( https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select/ ) which seems like it supports what I want to do - but its no longer supported.

Thanks
Dave

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can customize the contents of the dropdown with the [components framework](https://react-select.com/components) implemented into `react-select`. You have to overwrite the `Menu` component to add new content to the dropdown. You might also have to set some styles with the [styles api](https://react-select.com/styles).

```
const Menu = ({ children , ...props }) => {
    return <components.Menu>
        <div> My custom content </div>
        {children} // This contains the `MenuList` component with the options
    </components.Menu>
}

<Select
    { ... }
    components={{
        Menu
    }}
/>
```

To achieve something like Apples `Spotlight` feature you have to do some more advanced customisation. [This example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/z2q55m9lzl) shows a basic implementation of how you could do it.